# 'use' in annotations for Symfony errors

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to debug an error with Symfony, it keeps telling me:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Template" in method BReel\LVBundle\Entity\Journey::setJourneyOrder() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

I have put these 'use' statements in the file before defining the class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

Am I missing a some kind of inline declaration on my method that is defined in the same file?

```
/**
 * Set journey order
 *
 * @param integer $newOrder
 * @return Journey
 * @Template()
 */
public function setJourneyOrder($newOrder)
{
    $this->journeyOrder = $newOrder;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use `@Template` annotation you need to add following to your `use` list:

`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```